# When starting Spring Boot Web Application in external Tomcat, I ask a question about page 404

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8.5

When using Tomcat included in Boot, if a 404 error occurs, it succeeded in moving to the Custom page. However, if an external Tomcat is used, if a 404 error occurs, it will go to Tomcat's 404 page.

In situations where I can't explain tomcat's settings(For example i can't do setting error page in web.xml
), Could this issue be solved in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

Springboot has inbuilt tomcat server which will be started.
In following example xyz.html will work as your web.xml

```
@Bean
public ErrorPageRegistrar errorPage() {
 return registry -> registry.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/xyz.html"));  }
```